# Calling nodelet manager service from console

Tags: ros, service, nodelet, rosservice, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey.

My question concerns how to use the nodelet manager service properly.
Consider a nodelet manager has been started and is running.
It's rosservice to load a nodelet (/manager/load_nodelet) is also available.

What do I have to call now to, let's say, start the openni_camera nodelet (openni_camera/driver) via this service.

```
rosservice call /manager/load_nodelet "/nodelet_name" "openni_camera/driver" [] [] [] "nodelet_name1"
```

tells my 'success' and */nodelet_name* does appear under /manager/list topic for a couple of seconds, but vanishes after that with no debug message what so ever.

I am getting pretty frustrated over this, since the API has actually no documentation at all. (If you know different, PLEASE let me know about!)

Any suggestions?
Would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

Jasper

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46687/calling-nodelet-manager-service-from-console/) by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going now with another approach and just wanted to close this question.
Now I am using app_manager to run the nodelet launch file remotely. This actually works quiet smooth and exactly as I need it.
Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) with karma: 237 on 2012-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wouldn't call the service manually from command line. That's what the `nodelet` script in the `nodelet` package is for. Have a look at the [wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/nodelet) or execute

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet
```

for some information on using it.

If you really need/want to call the service directly from the command line, have a look at the source code of the nodelet binary (nodelet/src/nodelet.cpp).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on 2012-10-24**:
Thanks for your answer. Yes, you are right. If I just wanted to control nodelets from command line I would go the way you stated. Since I intend something different I wanted to gain some more information. But thanks anyway. Looking into source code is the only solution then. Cheers